# How to group by counts in R?

Tags: r

How to count the number of cases (similar to COUNT . . . GROUP BY in sql) ?

Here is my code that works

```
library(magrittr) 
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(dose=c("A", "B", "C","D", "E", "B","B", "E", "A","C", "C", "B"),
                 len=c(4.2, 10, 29.5,4.2, 10, 29.5,4.2, 10, 29.5,4.2, 10, 29.5))
mt_mean <-   df %>% group_by(dose) %>% summarise(avg_count = sum(len) )  
mt_mean
```

**But I want the counts NOT the sum**

So when I change `avg_count = sum(len)` to `avg_count = count(len)` 
The following error is thrown

```
Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: no applicable method for 'groups' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')".
```

How to group by counts in R?

Comment: `aggregate(len~dose, df, length)`

Comment: I like using `data.table` for this. `setDT(df); df[, .N, by = dose]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Staying with the `dplyr` library and using `summarise`:

```
mt_mean <- df %>% 
  group_by(dose) %>% 
  summarise(avg_count = n())
```

Alternatively, you can go even simpler in `dplyr` with `count` (per @Frank):

```
mt_mean <- df %>% 
  count(dose) %>%
  rename(avg_count = n)
```

This way, you also avoid an unnecessary grouping.

Either way, both approaches give you:

```
> mt_mean
# A tibble: 5 x 2
    dose avg_count
  <fctr>     <int>
1      A         2
2      B         4
3      C         3
4      D         1
5      E         2
```